# method of moments and maximum likelihood estimators

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I'm looking to find the estimate of $\mu$ for $n$ data using the method of moments and the maximum likelihood for the pdf given by
$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-(x-\mu)},  & \text{if} \, x \geq \mu \\
0, & \text{if} \, x \lt \mu\\
\end{cases}$

For the method of moments, I estimate

$\mu = \int_{\mu}^{\infty} x e^{\mu-x}dx, \text{for} \ x \geq \mu \ $ and

$\mu = \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} x 0 dx = 0, \text{for} \ x < \mu$

For the first cast, I simplify:

$\mu = e^{\mu}\int_{\mu}^{\infty} x e^{-x}dx = e^{\mu}(-e^{-x}x-\int-e^{-x}dx)$

$ \mu = 0 - e^{\mu}(-e^{-\mu}\mu-e^{-\mu}) = \mu e^0+ e^0$

$\mu = \mu + 1 \ $ Which is obviously erroneous.

For the maximum likelihood method, I first find log likelihood $l(\mu)$:

$\mathcal{l}(\mu) = \sum_i^n (\mu - x_i)ln(e) = n \mu - x_n $ with a derivative $n$. But since this is for $x \geq \mu$, these are not positive likelihoods. Since is it 0 elsewhere, and $ln(0) = -\infty$, I'm not sure how to approach this. EDIT: yes, these are positive likelihoods.

Am I integrating incorrectly in the method of moments case? Am I misunderstanding the max likelihood method? Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

For the maximum likelihood estimate observe that the joint density or likelihood function is given by
$$
\begin{align}
f(x_1\dotsc, x_n, \mu)&=I(x_1\geq \mu\dotsc, x_n\ge \mu) \times\prod_{i=1}^ne^{-{(x_i-\mu)}}\\
&=I(\min x_i\geq \mu )\times\prod_{i=1}^ne^{-{(x_i-\mu)}}\\
&\propto I(\min x_i\geq \mu )\times e^{n\mu}
\end{align}
$$
where the last line is proportional up to a positive constant and $I$ denotes indicator function. From the last expression it is clear that the MLE estimate is $\hat{\mu}=\min x_i.$

Comment: Thank you, Foobaz John. As a note to self, this can be seen visually by graphing the function and noting that the smallest $x_i \geq \mu$ will yield the most probable value.